# How to Rank scores Using sql Rank

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to rank some scores in the database but the output is wrong. i have done it before but I have forgotten how i did it.

**sql**

```
 SELECT `total_score`, FIND_IN_SET( `total_score`, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `total`
ORDER BY `total_score` DESC ) FROM `table` WHERE `class`="class" AND `session`="2018/2019")
) AS rank
FROM `table` WHERE `class`="class" AND `session`="2018/2019";
```

This are the data am working with for now
[image: scores]

**Output**
[image: Output]

From the output, the highest score is the one getting the lowest rank. I used group_concat because i want to be able to select some range of data with same class and session and then rank the total scores and i want the highest to be the first. **Hope that makes any sense**.

The data i was given i really large and i just want to be able to select the student classes, the academic session or whatever it is, their total score for that particular session and rank them.

Comment: Can you please show us a relevant part of your input data? Why do you do a group_concat just to parse out the stuff via find_in_set instead of using SQL Window Functions?

Comment: How is the guy having highest `total` score with lowest rank (rank = 3) !!!

Comment: thank you Madhur Bhaiya, That is the exact word i have been searching my head for.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the stated issue http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04eb16a/2

Comment: You can rank each row by counting the number of rows with score higher than current row. 0 rows means rank 1, 1 rows mean rank 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions of MySQL, I would recommend using variables:

```
SELECT total, (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CASTt.total + 0 as total
      FROM `table` t
      WHERE class = 'class' AND session = '2018/2019'
      ORDER BY total ASC
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rank := 0) params;
```

In MySQL 8+, you would do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.total, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total + 0 ASC) as the_rank
FROM `table` t
WHERE class = 'class' AND session = '2018/2019'
```

Comment: am using the latest version, the problem is, when i select everything and rank it, the query works perfectly but when i try to get only a group of data and then rank it,that is when i get the wrong value

Comment: And the output of your query is still the same as mine. the highest score still gets the lowest rank (100 ranks 3 ) @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @courage . . . If that is all, then just change the sort order.

Comment: am doing something wrong, just trying to figure out what it is

Comment: @courage . . . If you order by ascending, then 100 should have the largest order.  Unless you are storing the values as strings rather than numbers.

Comment: it true, i stored the data as string instead of number

Comment: @courage . . . That is a bad idea and that is your problem.

Comment: -  yea, but thanks tho... corrected it, wouldn't have noticed it without your help